# How can I include a div from another page?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I'm trying to scrape a few divs out of several of the intranet sites at work. and include them on a page I run locally (so I can look at one page instead of having 5 open). I'm guessing this is possible with JavaScript but I'm primitive with JavaScript so I'm not sure what I need to search for to find the answers. After I scrape the Div's from these other pages I want to add a refresh timer with something like setInterval()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This task is not as difficult as it should be, thanks to the glorious [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Repeat this for each of your URLs
  $.get("URL", function(data) {
    var resp = $(data); // Now you can do whatever you want with it
    $("#ID_OF_DIV", resp).appendTo("body");
  });
  // End Repeat

  setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload(true);
  }, 10000); // Refresh every ten seconds
});
```

Comment: the setTimeout seems to be causing the whole page to reload every 10 seconds, not sure why but thanks for the jQuery suggestion I'm trying this out. I'd upvote if I had enough rep yet

Comment: Causing the whole page to reload is what refreshes the content.  If you want to do it differently, you can move this code to a different function and use `setInterval`.  If you do this, dont forget to empty the body before appending new elements to it.

Comment: I just tried this out and I'm having some trouble getting it to work. I replaced "URL" with my test page and "#ID_OF_DIV" with "#Test" which is the id= of the div on the test page and nothing comes up. But if I remove "#ID_OF_DIV" from the 5th line the whole page shows as expected.

Comment: I'm not sure why but as soon as I nested my test div inside another div it started to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can to access those external pages using an `XMLHttpRequest` object, grab it's HTML source and strip just that information you want.

maybe this link can be useful: [Auto refresh `<DIV>` using ajax](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?threadid=169337)

Comment: Thanks I'm going to give this a try too and see which I like better. My gut tells me to avoid including jQuery just for this one task but I might end up needing it for other things in the future so I'm going to try that suggestion too